# HtmlAgilityPack : Can't parse endline (ignores end line)

Tags: c#, .net, html-agility-pack

I have the problem in parsing the following html:

```
<tr>
<td><p><b>
<span>Company:</span></b>
<span>Test</span>
</p></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><p><b>
<span>Company:</span></b>
<span>Test 2</span>
</p></td>
</tr>
```

my code is:

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.Load(@"email.txt");
Console.WriteLine(doc1.DocumentNode.InnerText);
```

I have the following output: `Company:TestCompany:Test 2`, but I want

```
Company: Test
Company: Test 2
```

So, the problem is that line breaks aren't being parsed.

P.S.: `doc.OptionWriteEmptyNodes = true;` makes no difference.

**Update:** I mean, whatever html is there it is not parsing end lines. Even if there are `<br />` tags or etc.

Comment: There is no line-break in your html. Even in your browser you wouldn't see it, both labels would be displayed side by side. What is your actual requirement? `Document.InnerText` just returns all text-controls value side by side. If you dont want that you have to select what you want(f.e. all spans) and then use `String.Join(Environment.NewLine, allInnerText)`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter, I want to get a string with InnerText as if I copied it from the Browser.
So if there are line breaks, they should be in innertext too (\n).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no line-break in your html. Even in your browser you wouldn't see it, both labels would be displayed side by side. What is your actual requirement? `Document.InnerText` just returns all text-controls value side by side.

If you dont want that you have to select what you want(f.e. all spans) and then use `String.Join(Environment.NewLine, allInnerText)`

```
var allInnerTexts = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//text()")
   .Select(n => n.InnerText.Trim())
   .Where(text => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(text));
Console.WriteLine(String.Join(Environment.NewLine, allInnerTexts));
```

Comment: @R.Matveev: well, i don't filter by tag names either, so you don't need filters for `span` etc. The `text` works for all

Comment: Does that mean that we just split the text by <tag>...</tag> anything that is between the tags?

Comment: @R.Matveev: it returns all text-nodes which contain text. So not anything between these tags but what is not a node by itself(you can nest html elements in each other) but plain text.